# Global authorization rule for a role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC application with fixed set of roles: `Admin, Management, Student`
One of the new roles (`Student`) should have limited access to the application.
I have lot of methods and don't want to write `[Authorize(...` attribute for each of them.

Is there a way to define them once for all of the methods?

Comment: Are you not already using the Authorize attribute? [`[Authorize(Role = "Student")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles)

Comment: You are thinking backwards. Unless you explicitly give that role permissions, it won't have any

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto @crowcoder In the project I'm working on there are no `[Authorize(Role = "...")]` attributes for most of the methods (there are 20+ controllers each with at least 10 methods). And they allow`Admin` and `Management` roles to call them. Does that mean, I have to specify for all of them the `Authorize` attribute without `Student` role?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why the downvote? Is it a bad question to ask if it can't be done globally without adding 200 lines of Authorize attribute for each method? I don't understand ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to define `Authorize` attribute also on a controller.

To define it only once I can use BaseController. When I have one common controller, that every other controller inherits from I can write this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Management")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{...
```

Then in some other controller:

```
public class ClassController : BaseController
{ 
    ...
    [Authorize(Roles = ("Administrator, Management, Student"))]
    public ActionResult Method()
    {
        ...
```

This will ensure that role `Student` will have access only to the `Method` and not any other method defined in any of the controllers.